# Use Method from another class without constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I'm trying to use a method from another class, but I think I can't really use the constructor
here is the first class :

```
public class Rules {
    public Rules(int size) {
        //body
    }

    public void methodINeed() {

    }
}
```

and I want to use the method in it in my second class,
but since if I use the constructor I have to give an int, which basically
screws up my calculations, i'm left with no idea of what to do,
what are my possibilities here?

Comment: Can methodIneed be made static?

Comment: You could make the method static. That way you don't need to create an instance of _Rules_. Not sure I understand how your calculations are affected by providing a constructor parameter though.

Answer (score 1):

just make another empty constructor:

```
public class Rules{
  public Rules(int size){
    //body
  }

 public Rules()
 {
    //body
  }

  public void methodIneed(){

  }
}
```

Then to access the method you need,

```
Rules x = new Rules();
x.methodINeed();
```

Comment: That might break other methods that depend on the initialization done by the existing constructor.

Comment: Yes it does,
i can't really even use methods through my second constructor,
it also makes everything repeat, do you think i should use a seperate class for the Method?

Answer (score 0):

You can access methods of other classes without contructing them if you declare those methods static:

```
public class Rules{
  public Rules(int size){
    //body
  }
  public static void methodIneed(){

  }
}
```

Comment: Given that there is no parameterless constructor, and the method is not already static, I suspect that `methodIneed()` needs things to be initialized by the constructor, but perhaps OP can shed some light on this scenario.

Comment: Yeah, but but what if the medhod i need, is set to change
i want to display a board which gets filled with information,
does the static hinder me from doing so?

Comment: you can access all information/fields within the static method as far as yout fields are also declared static. If you can do this you can go this way.

Comment: If your method doesn't access anything else from the class that is not static, then no. You can't access an instance variable from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to review the design of your classes why in the earth you have to call a method in other class for calculations purpose ???

possible solution:

- mix two classes
- add third class ( for instance Helper class) and call HelperClass.calculateForMe(sth)